# Bigcommerce - Fail to verify the load callbacks

Tags: php, bigcommerce

hello fellow developers,

I’m facing an issue with the load callback (and the uninstall callback by extension).
I’m trying to verify the requests authenticity following the algorithm described in the documentation. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/apps/load#signed-payload

I am able to decode the json string and the data is correct, but the signatures never match. I made sure to use the right client secret and tried out different encoding/decoding scenarios with no luck.

An other concern is with the snippet of code (PHP) they provide in example (and in their [sample app](https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex/blob/master/index.php)). They seem to return null when the signatures match and the decoded data when they don’t… ([try secureCompare()](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d9bced715bf34e9fd9cc663f7c464fdb5ab1816))
Meaning that the security test would pass every time, since in all my attempts the signatures didn’t match.

Am I missing something here ?

Edit: Here is the example in the doc. I can't really give you sample data as the client secret is to remain secret...

```
function verify($signedRequest, $clientSecret)
{
    list($payload, $encodedSignature) = explode('.', $signedRequest, 2); 

    // decode the data
    $signature = base64_decode($encodedSignature);
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode($payload), true);

    // confirm the signature
    $expectedSignature = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $clientSecret, $raw = true);

    if (secureCompare($signature, $expectedSignature)) {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
    }

    return $data;
}

function secureCompare($str1, $str2)
{
    $res = $str1 ^ $str2;
    $ret = strlen($str1) ^ strlen($str2); //not the same length, then fail ($ret != 0)
    for($i = strlen($res) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $ret += ord($res[$i]);
    }
    return !$ret;
}
```

Comment: Please add some code you've tried so far

Comment: Since it's a `TOTP` in question, it appears that time sync between your and their server is off. You should sync your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything, and it's not a clock sync issue - the 28 lines of sample code provided both [here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/apps/load#signed-payload) and [here](https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex/blob/ab27958eea6b55a00ee9a776a81187d78f7d091d/index.php) has some pretty critical flaws:

1. The sample code does a `hash_hmac` of the raw base64-**encoded** JSON, instead of the base64-decoded JSON. (The hash provided to you by the BigCommerce API is really a hash of the base64-**decoded** JSON).
2. Since `hash_hmac` is called with `$raw=true`, this means the two strings will always be vastly different: one is raw binary, and the other is hexits.
3. Bad check of `secureCompare` logic. The `if (secureCompare...` part of the `verify` function expects opposite behavior from the `secureCompare` function. If the secureCompare function returns true when the strings match, why are we calling `error_log`?

Put all three of these issues together, and you end up with code that appears to work, but is actually silently failing. If you use the sample code, you're likely allowing any and all "signed" requests to be processed by your application!

Here's my corrected implementation of the `verify` function:

```
<?php

function verifySignedRequest($signedRequest, $clientSecret)
{
    list($encodedData, $encodedSignature) = explode('.', $signedRequest, 2);

    // decode the data
    $signature = base64_decode($encodedSignature);
    $jsonStr = base64_decode($encodedData);
    $data = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

    // confirm the signature
    $expectedSignature = hash_hmac('sha256', $jsonStr, $clientSecret, $raw = false);
    if (!hash_equals($expectedSignature, $signature)) {
        error_log('Bad signed request from BigCommerce!');
        return null;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was unable to get an answer from them 6 month ago... So it was kind of ironic to receive a security update in my mailbox today, linking to my own post...

Comment: @oumlaote: Oh wow, BigCommerce sent out a security update email? I didn't receive one, but I'd love to see a copy of it if you're comfortable forwarding it to me. :D